# LaTeX equation numbers with Emacs

Tags: latex, auctex, completion, lsp, autocompletion

Equation labels in the .tex document are `\label{eq:3}`, e.g., which is (7) on the output pdf-document (say); `\eqref{eq:3}` references this equation.

Typing <C-x-o> at point (`|` in the following block), Vim offers both references for completion in this dropdown:

```
\eqref{eq:|
       eq:1      Equation (1) [p.2]
       …
       eq:3      Equation (7) [p.3]
       …
```

What are possible settings to achieve similar integrated completion experience in Emacs?

Comment: Look into `reftex` which is builtin and does this sort of thing.

Comment: Hmm: reftex works, but offers only the labels as `eq:1`, but not the equation numbers (1). What am I missing here?

Comment: It offers the labels and context which, IMO, is easier to understand than the rendered equation number (which may change has you add more equations).  Sorry if that is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a capability of the LSP server.  With [TexLab](https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab), it can look like this:
[image]

You need to install a LSP server and activate it within Emacs, I did <kbd>M-x eglot RET</kbd> and took `texlab`.

Comment: Wow, excellent, exactly what I wanted to have, thank you.

Comment: @AloisPichler - You're welcome.  The usual practice is to mark the answer as accepted in order to make the question disappear from the unanswered questions bucket.

Comment: Yes, if the answer is satisfactory, the best way to thank the person who answered it is to [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer. That also helps future visitors (maybe even you) determine that a question they might have has already a satisfactory answer. Accepting it is the more important task for you (only you can do it), but you (and anybody else) can also vote up the answer if you (they)  think it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is perhaps less elegant than that in the LSP-based answer, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to share.  It looks like this:

[image: my cool picture]

You can search by label or equation number (as it appears in the PDF), with a live preview.

If you're interested, this setup is achieved by installing the packages [czm-preview](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-preview.el), [czm-tex-fold](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-fold.el), [czm-tex-ref](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-ref.el), [czm-tex-compile](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-compile.el) and their common dependency [czm-tex-util](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-util.el) (or see my [config](https://github.com/ultronozm/emacsd) for an overkill "one-step" setup).